# JSON parse Number as String

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

What is best way to parse JSON number as String in javascript

```
Example:
{
  "a": 10.00
}
```

Notice 
I do not have control over value 10.00. 
I cannot add there "+''".
I want to keep the decimal places, but it is not rule that there have to be 2 decimals.

Result should be 10.00 not 10

Comment: `JSON.parse` will do just fine. The actual number representation for `10` and `10.00` are exactly the same. If you want to **display/format** the number in a certain way then you can use `.toFixed`: `(10)..toFixed(2)`. If you want to display the number exactly how it is written in the JSON document then you are out of luck. The value would have to be provided as a string.

Comment: You need "a" to be the string "10.00" ?

Comment: @ariel yes, but I do not have control over this value. I cannot simply add " character.

Comment: The options I would not recommend: 1) Implement your own JSON parser or find one that can be extended so that all number values can be converted to strings. 2) Do some regex magic (which can easily fail if your input can vary a lot).

Comment: Why do you want/need to do that anyway?

Comment: Looking at your question: no you don't. You want to _show_ that value to users at some point, with 2 decimals after the decimal point. So do that instead, as per Felix's comment. Use JSON.parse, which will make it the number 10, and then format it only at the time it needs to be displayed.

Comment: I need to render correct value that includes decimal places. The input is not in my hand.

Comment: yes, and _you do that using .toFixed(2)_, you don't change the input at all, you just use `<p class="amount">${{ parsed.a.toFixed(2) }}</p>` or whatever your render engine's equivalent is.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, it will not help me the value can have 3 or x decimals. As I mentioned length of decimals is not fixed.

Comment: then you're going to have to live with the fact that Javacript _cannot see_ the difference between 10 and 10.00: they're literally the same value at runtime. If you need it to be strings, then either send your json with quotes around the value (e.g. `"10.00"` not `10.00`, `"1.928346"`, not `1.928346`, etc) but if you can't do that, then you are out of luck: write code that checks whether there is a fractional value, if there is, use the number directly, and if there isn't, use toFixed(...) if you always want to see a minimum number of decimal places.

Comment: If the number digits other than `0` in the decimal places then just converting the number to a string will do the right thing. The problem is only with decimals that are all `0`. Depending on what the number represents, whether the user sees `10` or `10.00` doesn't matter since they both represent the same value. As so often, more context would be useful.

Comment: If you are being given data that needs to be output directly as is, it has to be a string.  The folks who give you the json data should know that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need exactly the same number of decimals, the only way is if the JSON present the value as string. If you have no control over the source, you could edit the JSON before parsing, adding the quotes, but that could bring several problems. This needs to be tested toroughly.

```js
json = '{ "a": 10.00, "b":2.1020, "d":0.20,"c": "21" }';

json = json.replace(/:\s*[^"0-9.]*([0-9.]+)/g, ':"$1"');

console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Comment: Just to emphasise, that **This needs to be tested toroughly** notice is very important to pay attention to, and if you use this approach, remember to add tests because it can just as easily completely break other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to extract the value of `a` property, before JSON string is parsed and string `10.00` is converted to the number `10`:

```js
const jsonString = `{
  "a": 10.00
}`
const aString = jsonString.match(/[,{]\s*\"a\":\s*([0-9.]+)/m)[1]
console.log(aString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse with a reviver argument

```js
const json = '{"a":{"b":0.1}}'

const data = JSON.parse(json, (_key, value, data) => typeof value === 'number' ? data.source : value)

console.log(data);
```